# I cannot find my PCG Sony VAIO model on their support site

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, sony-vaio

I have a PCG-61611M laptop. On both UK and US Sony sites, this model is unknown. Their own detector app doesn't help.

What now? I need drivers!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s too specific for a basic issue which is simply identifying hardware in Windows; meaning this tip is very generic.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Start and Run. In the box, enter MSINFO32 and click OK. In the System Summary, see System Model. This is your actual model and often start VPC*, as opposed to the B/S they print on the bottom. I can only assume they still have lead pipes in Sony HQ.